# Display Image to right of text in TreeView in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode

I have a `TreeView` to popup my Menu. When I add a new `TreeNode` with an image to the `TreeView` by default the image is appearing in the left of the `TreeNode` Text.

My aspx code is

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows" ExpandDepth="1" NodeIndent="10"
        BackColor="White" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Andalus"
        Font-Size="Small">
        <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" />
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Parent 1" Value="Print">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Node 1" Value="01"></asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Node 2" Value="02"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Parent 2" Value="03"></asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Parent 3" Value="04" ImageUrl="images/blinking_new.gif">
            </asp:TreeNode>                
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Parent 4" Value="05"></asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
        <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="5px"
            NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
        <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
        <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px"
            BackColor="#FF99CC" ImageUrl="" />
    </asp:TreeView>
```

And the Output is

[image]

**But I want that the image should be appear in the right of the Text.**

Like:

[image]

How to do this ? Is there any property of `TreeNode` to do this OR I have to write a `css` for this.
I have also searched alot but not able to solve.

Your valuable suggestion will be highly appreciate.

Comment: Can you place the image inside the `treenode` tags? I'm not sure but maybe it can help you.

Comment: No it will not supported

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<asp:TreeNode Text="Parent 3" Value="04" ImageUrl="images/blinking_new.gif" class="new">
</asp:TreeNode>
```

and in your css

```
.new image { 
    float: right; 
    /*try maybe also to use relative position*/
}
```

Comment: thank you. `TreeNode` doesn't have a property `CssClass`. But I have add it to the `NodeStyle` but  sadly it didn't work

Comment: Maybe use the html attribute `class` instead of the asp class `CssClass`?